# How to bias a voltage for an ADC

Tags: circuit-analysis, biasing

I am part of a project that is implementing a power storage system. The storage device voltage must be monitored in order to direct power. The storage device voltage should remain between 12 and 36 V. The project uses a [TI TMS320F28027 MCU](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tms320f28027.pdf) which operates at 3.3 V. How can the 12 to 36 V be mapped onto 0 to 3.3 V for the MCU.

I posted a similar [question here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/353181/implementing-a-voltage-sensor-with-voltage-dividing-resistors) but it specified that the voltage would range from 0 to 60 V. The difference for this question is how to bias the voltage appropriately.

I also posted [another question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/354989/115818) about biasing the output of a current sensor for an ADC, but it involved biasing a balanced voltage around 0 V. I am having trouble adapting the answer to this problem. Diagram from answer:

[image: diagram from answer]
 <sup>*Figure 1. Diagram from previous answer*</sup>

An attempt to emulate the design methodology would be:

24 V maps to 1.65 V 
38 V maps to 3.3 V  
10 V maps to 0 V

The most basic circuit model:

[image]

How to design the  bias?

Comment: Is a negative voltage rail available this time?

Comment: yes there is a negative rail

Comment: Are you going to share the voltage?

Comment: the dual supply source is [XP Power IZ2415S](https://www.xppower.com/Portals/0/pdfs/SF_IZ.pdf), it can supply +/- 100 mA at +/- 15 V. There are 2 [LEM LAH 100-P](http://www.lem.com/docs/products/lah_100-p.pdf) sensors running of the source. They each draw 10 mA in addition to 1/2000 of the current sensed. They are each expected to sense an average of + 70 A which amounts to 90 mA total. I don't know what is meant in the power source datasheet by +/- 100 A.

Comment: Is your power system DC or AC??? I would expect AC from your \$\pm 11\:\text{mA}\$ on the schematic. But I expect DC from your statement that \$10\:\text{V}\$ should map to \$0\:\text{V}\$ (because, otherwise, what should \$-10\:\text{V}\$ and \$-38\:\text{V}\$ map to??)  So what is the deal? Is this an AC system or a DC system. I'm confused. Also, it appears you have two questions -- (1) mapping the system voltage to within the ADC range; and (2) mapping the Hall Effect sensor range to with a similar ADC range. .... I admit, I'm confused right now. What exactly are you doing/asking?

Comment: Also, for measuring the voltage, what kind of load can you allow for making that measurement? (I can work out the allowed load given the Hall Effect measurement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearranging:

- 38 V maps to 3.3 V
- 24 V maps to 1.65 V
- 10 V maps to 0 V

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBrd2X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. An 11.5:1 potential divider.*

The simplest solution is to use a potential divider with a ratio of 38:3.3 or 11.5:1. This would result in:

- 38 V maps to 3.3 V
- 24 V maps to 2.08 V
- 10 V maps to 0.868 V

The 0.868 V offset can be removed in software. Again, you lose a little resolution with this approach.

If a negative voltage supply is available then the offset can be removed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFJJ3N.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. With a negative rail available the offset at minimum input voltage can be removed.*

How:

- The span is 38 - 10 = 28 V.
- This has to be scaled to 3.3 V so a divider ratio of 28 / 3.3 = 8.5:1. Let's use 7.5k and 1k to give us the required ratio.

Now we need to figure out the negative reference voltage.

- At 10 V in Vout will be 0 V. With the 8.5:1 ratio we will need to hold Vref at \$ - \frac {1}{8.5} 10 = -1.18 V \$.

So, R1 = 7.5k, R2 = 1k, Vref = -1.18 V should do the trick.

I'll leave it to you to work out how to create the reference voltage.

Answer (score 1):

"Mapping" is a good description, but level shifting is mostly what is needed.
If you source voltage is 12 volts to 36 volts (n), then use n/10 to get 1.2 volts to 3.6 volts. Subtract 1.2 volts to get 0 - 2.4 volts.

Use an op-amp with a gain of 1.375 to get a range of 0 to 3.3 volts.
An op-amp with a negative supply of -3.3 volts will allow an output as low as zero volts

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgLU3d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>