# How to filter a signal through a differential amplifier

Tags: adc, filtering

An input signal must be scaled and biased for an ADC ([MCU is TMS320F28027](http://www.ti.com/product/TMS320F28027/technicaldocuments)). I following an answer for a [previous post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/355241/115818).
[image]
 <sup>*Figure 1: Original answer*</sup>

If the signal needs to be filtered with a cutoff frequency of 5 kHz would adding the following capacitors be correct?
 (according to f<sub>cutoff</sub>= 1/(2πRC)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHNsIP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How was the orignal capacitance of C1 chosen? is it better to maintain C1's value and change R3 and R4 to satisfy f<sub>c</sub>? Is C2 necessary to filter (its inclusion was based on another answer)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to filter a signal through a differential amplifier

Just to be clear about this; the circuit in the question is using an op-amp to produce a level shift so, stricty speaking there is only one input signal that might require to be filtered hence I'm not answering this as if it were a true differential amplifier requiring balanced filtering.

> How was the orignal capacitance of C1 chosen?

The original capacitor (100 nF) was chosen such that the parallel combination of R3 and R4 gave a cut-off frequency of: -

\$f_c = \dfrac{1}{2\pi RC}\$ where R = R3||R4

So, plugging the numbers in you get Fc = 33.95 Hz. Clearly it wasn't chosen to give a cut-off of 5 kHz. If you used 0.636 nF then the cut-off frequency would be 5338 Hz.

> is it better to maintain C1's value and change R3 and R4 to satisfy
> fc?

If you need the ratio of R3 and R4 to be precise this will constrain things so, to answer that part is impossible but, in some applications, if a precise filter response is needed, 1% (or better) capacitors are used with a provision to add a smaller parallel capacitor to make fine adjustments.

> Is C2 necessary to filter (its inclusion was based on another answer)?

Without C2 you have a simple 1st order low pass filter and by adding C2 you get a 2nd order low pass filter but with some limitations. The limitation is because the non-inverting gain amplifier has a minimum gain of 1 even at high frequencies therefore, above the cut-off point, the rate at which signals get smaller with a rising frequency is less steep than it would be for a more conventional 2nd order low pass filter.

Given what components you might have and the limited gain of the op-amp stage you have set, it might be preferable to make a proper 2nd order low pass filter using a sallen-key approach. Note that Rb (below) can connect to your 1.5 volt reference AND, you can attenuate the input as per your original question by adding a resistor from the junction of R1 and R2 to ground: -

[image]

The difference between a 1st order and decent 2nd order filter is shown below: -

[image]

Pictures from [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/opamp78.gif).

Comment: Will the opamp have sufficient UGBW to guarantee a rolloff out to 100MHz? or to 10MHz? or to 1MHz?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf if you choose the correct one yes.